# Skip subsequent Mocha tests from spec if one fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I can't find a way how to stop some part of `it`'s from run if one of them failed

I'm using `mocha-as-promised`, so the code might look different from as usuall

```js
describe("remote promises", function() {
  describe("browsing", function() {
    describe("getting page", function() {
      it("should navigate to test page and check title", function() {
        this.timeout(TIMEOUT);
        return browser.get("http://admc.io/wd/test-pages/guinea-pig.html").then(function() {
          return browser.title();
        }).then(function(title) {
          return assert.ok(~title.indexOf("I am a page title - Sauce Labs"), "Wrong title!");
        });
      })
      it("submit element should be clicked1", function() {
        this.timeout(TIMEOUT);
        return browser.elementById("submit").then(function(el) {
          return browser.clickElement(el);
        }).then(function() {
            return browser["eval"]("window.location.href");
          }).then(function(location) {
            assert.ok(~location.indexOf("http://"), "Wrong location!");
          });
      })
    });
    describe("clicking submit", function() {
      it("submit element should be clicked2", function() {
        this.timeout(TIMEOUT);
        return browser.elementById("submit").then(function(el) {
          return browser.clickElement(el);
        }).then(function() {
            return browser["eval"]("window.location.href");
          }).then(function(location) {
            assert.ok(~location.indexOf("http://"), "Wrong location!");
          });
      });
    });

  });
});
```

and i want that if `should navigate to test page and check title` is failed then 
`submit element should be clicked1` should be skipped

EDIT:
seems i'm just making my tests wrong, will wait for some time before deleting question

**EDIT:**

as i replied in comment - i already received this answer in mocha google groups, but there are some other restrictions i not mentioned in question - i'm using grunt-simple-mocha and as i inspected code - there is no bail option when i pass options to mocha constructor

i failed to find where are options from command line are passed to Suite instance, and the only line where it may be as i see it is a

```
suite.bail(this.bail());
```

which looks weird for me

i think i will open issue at mocha github pages, maybe they will extend passed options with bail setting later, or just explain me what i did wrong and how i can solve my problem in other way

**EDIT: and now, according to https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/commit/f0b441ceef4998e570a794dcff951bf2330eb0c5
latest Mocha have bail option from the box. Thanks to authors!**

Comment: This question also is helpful if one searches for: mocha failfast or failure on first error.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Mocha supports bailing after the first test failure, is that what you want?

From `mocha --help`:

```
-b, --bail                      bail after first test failure
```

Comment: yes, thanks for answer. i already received this answer in mocha google groups page. i will accept it since it's correct answer to my original question, but i will append my question with short description what i actually wanted. maybe you can take a look and extend your answer, but seems mocha can't do what i want right now

Comment: now Mocha have bail option that can be passed via `options` too

Comment: As @llamerr mentioned, just put `--bail` inside a file called `mocha.opts` if you want this by default.