# Bail suite on mocha (sub)suite error but continue next?

Tags: node.js, testing, bdd, mocha.js

I'm using mocha in node.js with have bdd-style specs.

Is it possible to bail a sub-suite after the first error but continue it's parent/sibling suites?

Say I test different routes to access an api, then I want to abort a specific route if it's connection fails because there's no use hammering with calls if first action failed, but it can still attempt to check other things.

If a high level tests sees a server is completely down or misconfigured then I could abort instead of having to wait all the failing tests to timeout and fill the report with unnecessary mayhem.

I see the following answer but that's not what I want, it bails everything, which is too much. I want something to only bail a branch in the spec tree if an assertion fails.

[Skip subsequent Mocha tests from spec if one fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954531/skip-subsequent-mocha-tests-from-spec-if-one-fails)

Comment: what was your use case for this? Just curious. Sounds like you had several groups of tests, and in one of the groups if one test fails, you know the rest are gonna conk out too, so why bother continuing with that particular group of test cases?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, it was a long time ago. I think it was to get more usable results from a single test run to help diagnose the problems. Like if one suite fails it is still useful to see what the other suites do, but this gets very messy if every test in a particular suite fails for the same reason. So I wanted to run all suites, abort a suite at its first error and continue to next suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want mocha to continue processing other test files after failing on one, you could use find to run a separate instance of mocha on each file:

```
find test/ -name "*.js" -exec mocha {} \;
```

Comment: Good tip, although I was hoping for a bit more granular control this is better then bailing everything on first error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [`mocha-steps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-steps) may work for this:

> Global `step()` function, as a drop-in replacement for `it()`. Any failing step will abort the parent `describe` immediately. This is handy for BDD-like scenarios, or smoke tests that need to run through specific steps.