# How to stop the test running if one of the 'it' sections fails?

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io, wdio-v6

My test suite contains several 'it' sections within the 'describe'.

If one of the 'it' sections fails (e.g. if it can't find an element) - it jumps straight to the next 'it' section and carries on the test.

If an 'it' section fails I just want the test to stop running and be marked as a fail.

How do you do this?

Comment: That's what's *supposed* to happen. The `describe` defines a suite of related *but separate* tests, if they actually depend on one another (i.e. need to be run in a particular order) they should be a single `it` spec.

Comment: Jasmine has an option to stop immediately after a fail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31809311/9741277

Comment: @jonrsharpe. That makes sense. Unfortunately I have inherited these tests. The 'it' sections are used as paragraphs to make the test more readable. Is there anyway I can cause the failure of one of the 'its' to end the whole 'describe'. Basically if an element is not found I want the whole suite to stop running.

Comment: @leun4m Thanks but I am using Mocha

Comment: Well then this might be what you are searching for (the `bail`-flag) https://stackoverflow.com/a/13959934/9741277

Comment: Perfect thanks @leun4m

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip subsequent Mocha tests from spec if one fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954531/skip-subsequent-mocha-tests-from-spec-if-one-fails)

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this was to use the `bail` flag within the mochaOpts section of `wdio.conf` as shown here:

```js
mochaOpts: {
    bail: true
},
```

Thanks to [@leun4m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9741277/leun4m) for this answer

Comment: WebdriverIO has a 'bail' option as well (https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html#bail). But it does note that some extra configuration may be needed, which is where this answer might be best.